# Unable to Understand o/p of Float.toHexString() method in java

Tags: java

I want  to know  how  to get  hexadecimal  representation of  float number.
 I tried  following  code

```
      System.out.println(Float.toHexString(56));
```

Got  o/p

```
  0x1.cp5
```

I  really do not understand. If I use  `Integer method` the o/p would be  38, which I can understand...but how  o/p comes   `0x1.cp5`. Could any one  tell me   or  point  to  some  good tutorial..thanks  in advance.

Comment: This method isn't intended to be easy for a human to read.  It is used for precise representation of floating point values (very rarely) If you are having trouble understanding it, most likely you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) to see what happens to your float when represented in [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) format. 
 56 in binary is `111000` which when [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_number)  converts to `1.11000`.

As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toHexString%28float%29) says, `0x1.` is for the `significand` part, which is in this case '1100' in binary, which is 'c' in hex. And the exponent part is 5.

Answer (score 3):

Just refer to `java.lang.Float` javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toHexString%28float%29

> - If m is a float value with a normalized representation, substrings are used to represent the significand and exponent fields. The
>     significand is represented by the characters "0x1." followed by a
>     lowercase hexadecimal representation of the rest of the significand as
>     a fraction. Trailing zeros in the hexadecimal representation are
>     removed unless all the digits are zero, in which case a single zero is
>     used. Next, the exponent is represented by "p" followed by a decimal
>     string of the unbiased exponent as if produced by a call to
>     Integer.toString on the exponent value.
> - If m is a float value with a subnormal representation, the significand is represented by the characters "0x0." followed by a
>     hexadecimal representation of the rest of the significand as a
>     fraction. Trailing zeros in the hexadecimal representation are
>     removed. Next, the exponent is represented by "p-126". Note that there
>     must be at least one nonzero digit in a subnormal significand.

Comment: beat me to it! +1 for that! :)